# How do I supply the view with all necessary query data in Symfony / MVC frameworks?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig, symfony

Bit of a beginner question about Symfony2/3 here.

Say I'm building a page to display an article. I create a route like "/articles/{id}", link that to a controller which queries the database for the relevant article dataset and pass that on to a Twig view template to display everything. So far, so simple.

But what if I wanted to also include a "Related posts" section at the bottom of the page, which presents other articles with similar topics that might also be of interest. Or a sidebar with numerous other widgets that all require their own logic and database queries.

So, how do I go about supplying every element of the final page with the required data? Do I anticipate every single element of the view and query the data that will be needed beforehand in the controller, to hand it over in bulk? (But if so, what if I modified my sidebar template and switched the widgets around. Would I then have to update the logic in every controller on my site that leads to a page with the sidebar?) Or do I just somehow call back additional data from inside the view when needed?

Coming from simpler stuff like Wordpress where the logic is freely mixed within the view and PHP functions can be called whenever, the seemingly strict and/or desired separation between the view and the logic is introducing a new data flow I'm still trying to wrap my head around. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Hope You can achieve this by embedding Controllers in a Template:

```
<div id="sidebar">
{{ render(controller(
    'AppBundle:Article:recentArticles',
    { 'max': 3 }
)) }}
</div>
```

Refer : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html